# mount failed, reason given by server: Permission denied

Tags: linux, centos, mount, nfs

I am using centos. I am trying to mount a server directory to the local directory.

server:10.10.10.1
client:10.10.10.2

the /etc/exports at the server has this content 
`/logs/user *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)`

---

When I run the command `# showmount -e 10.10.10.1`, it shows,
`Export list for 10.10.10.1:
/logs/user *`

now when I try to mount `mount -t nfs 10.10.10.1:/logs/user /mnt/nfs/home`
I am getting this: 
`mount: 10.10.10.1:/logs/user failed, reason given by server: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

Try these following points:-

1. You need to run the command on the server after modifying the /etc/exports file:

   exportfs -a
2. Check your **/etc/exports** file and make sure that the volume is exported and that your client has the right kind of access to it. For example, if a client only has read access then you have to mount the volume with the **ro** option rather than the **rw** option.
3. services running on nfs clients

   ```
   chkconfig --list|grep rpc


   rpcbind         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
   rpcgssd         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
   rpcidmapd       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
   rpcsvcgssd      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off

   chkconfig --list|grep nfs

   nfs             0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
   nfslock         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
   ```
4. check NFS Server logs
5. If you are using RedHat base system then check if `selinux` is properly set. Disable `selinux` temporary by `setenforce 0` command and test.

Comment: Had the same problem, solved by running ```sudo exportfs -a```

Answer (score 0):

Please check server logs for more details:
/var/log/messages

Please make sure "/logs/user" is not already a mount point on the server!

For eg:
you mount an NFS share to "/logs/user" on the server and then re-export it to the client, that is not supported.

Please see whether selinux is turned ON on the server:
    #sestatus

If it is turned ON you need to check /var/log/audit.log for more details

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me today. After restarting the NFS service I've realized that I had changed the names of a couple of directories declared in `/etc/exports`.

So, check every path, restart your NFS service and verify it load without errors.